# How to center everything in html webpage without being affected by zooming?

Tags: html, css

I'm not so expert in HTML and CSS. I've tried my best to create a webpage. But while zooming it seems broken. Only the logo and language switcher is broken. Don't know how to fix this. Can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue, please? 
This is my Webpage link: corailhelico.com

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have a header with a logo and language switcher.

I have used a header div with logo and language div `with flex`.

Ps: don't use margin with px like `"450px"` for align element, it's not `responsive at all`.

> Flex guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
html, body {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:0;
}

.header {
  height:80px;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.header .logo {
  display:flex;
  margin:auto;
}

.header img {
  width:180px;
  height:50px;
}

.header .language {
  margin:0 0 auto 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.corailhelico.com/images/corail-logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="language">Language</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and on my double-screen, [here](http://i.imgur.com/9HuT8Pe.jpg), don't use a static width if you want a div with the width of the screen. Use `100%` and remove your `left, right, bottom, top`, it's useless in your case.